# Angular-chart copied from example not showing up

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

Here's a plunker of my code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKNNjx

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="doughnut.data" chart-labels="doughnut.labels" options="doughnut.options" height="100" width="200">
</canvas>
```

The plunker works, and all the includes and everything - it's the same as in my project. I've created the plunker from that. But in my project, the chart is showing up as blank. No errors or anything. I can't even reproduce it in the plunker.

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly go wrong so that my code would show a blank canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in 0.7.3 version of the angular-chart it's just data, not chart-data..